# Newest unanswered questions with my tags

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, unanswered-questions, tag-watching

Is there a way (or can I suggest making this possible) to show questions with "my tags" sorted in order of newest to oldest... instead of most votes to least votes?

The reason I ask is that it seems like the top few pages of questions with "my tags" are pretty static (and many of the questions were asked at least a year ago).  It takes time to look for something reasonably tractable that has not already been sufficiently answered.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I understand that you're referring to [Unanswered/my tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags). That page is indeed not very useful, and in fact [SE plans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251095/259867) to remove "Unanswered" from the site interface.

However, you can use [this search link](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20isanswered%3ano%20hasaccepted%3ano%20score%3a0..%20closed%3ano) to achieve the same effect that sorting that tab by newest would do. Just bookmark it.

---

Explanation of the above search query:

```
intags:mine isanswered:no hasaccepted:no score:0.. closed:no
```

- `intags:mine`: has one of your favorite tags
- `isanswered:no`: has no answer with a positive score
- `hasaccepted:no`: has no accepted answer
- `score:0..` has nonnegative score. You can omit this if you want; I include it because this is the behavior of the Unanswered tab.
- `closed:no` not closed. Same reason as the previous item.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "custom filters" for this.

To open the interface for creating a new custom filter, you can do the following:

1. Navigate to the [Home](https://math.stackexchange.com/) page or [Questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions) page.
2. On the right sidebar, below the community bulletin, you will find a panel titled "Custom Filters". There, click on "[Create a custom filter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?edited=true)".

Alternatively,

1. Navigate to the [Questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions) page.
2. Click on the "[Filter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?edited=true)" tab, which can be found to the right of the sorting tabs.

Now, you can apply various options to your filter. Don't forget to click on "Save custom filter" once you are satisfied. You can find your saved filters in the "Custom Filters" panel in the right sidebar. If there are new posts matching your filter, then a blue dot appears next to that filter in the "Custom Filters" panel.<sup>$\dagger$</sup>

For your specific use-case, you might prefer to make the following selections:

- Filter by: "No answers"
- Sorted by: "Newest"
- Tagged with: "My watched tags"

The same process can be used on the Meta site as well.

---

##### Related links

- Feature announcement on Meta SE: [Custom Filters release announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330326)
- <sup>$\dagger$</sup>A blue indicator is also supposed to appear on these new posts when you click on that filter, but this indicator is currently not appearing on any new posts. A bug report regarding this is filed on Meta SE: ["Questions with new activity" in custom filters don't get new/read indicator as expected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371895)